# Align only one span center

Tags: html, css

Basically I have the following:

```
<td>
<span id="sp1">foo</span>
<span id="sp12">foo</span>
</td>
```

How can I align `sp1` on the `left` and `sp2` on the `center`?

I have tried using `text-align` and the `position` attributes but none worked.

This didn't work, for instance:

```
<td style="text-align:left">
<span id="sp1">foo</span>
<span style="text-align:center" align="center" id="sp12">foo</span>
</td>
```

Comment: @SMAKSS not sure it is a wise idea to reset display for a td to flex

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Yea, `td` won't work with flexbox at all, but they are based on something common.

Comment: `span` is an inline element. it doesn't support text alignment. It gets its alignment from the closest block or inline-block element. You could use `display: inline-block; width: n` where n is a static width. Or you could use flex-box on a wrapping element. Or use floats.

Answer (score 0):

Aside  `text-align` you could use `float`:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, white 50%, gray 50%);/* show center */
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

#sp1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="sp1">foo</span>
      <span id="sp12">foo</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To set `#sp2` right on the middle, `transform` can finalize it , **but it can then overflow the floatting element**:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, white 50%, gray 50%);/* show center */
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

#sp1 {
  float: left;
}
#sp12 {
display:inline-block;
transform:translatex(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="sp1">foo</span>
      <span id="sp12">foo</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```